unstructured cannot find images
I am trying to use the unstructured library to convert a word document into a json file. However, for some reason it is not seeing the images; in the list of elements that are returned there should be elements of type "Image". It is not throwing an error, it's just not returning the image elements. Below my code and my test file. The testfile contains a string, an image and another string. But the image is thus not detected. What am I doing wrong?
from unstructured.partition.docx import partition_docx
import os
# Set environment variables
os.environ['UNSTRUCTURED_API_KEY'] = "your unstructured.io api key"
os.environ['UNSTRUCTURED_API_URL'] = "https://api.unstructuredapp.io/general/v0/general"

elements = partition_docx(filename="input/test.docx")

with open("input/test.docx", "rb") as f:
    elements = partition_docx(file=f)
    elements = [element.to_dict() for element in elements]
    # save as json
    with open("output/test.json", "w") as f_json:
        json.dump(elements, f_json, indent=2)

My project structure:
├── root
│   └── input
│   └── output

Here's the file: test.docx

The file you shared appears to have been deleted, so there's no way for people to reproduce what you did. Also, just installing and importing partition_docx from unstructured.partition.docx appears to hang Python, so I'm not sure this is a package you should be using. At any rate, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'. Finally, in your example you define elements twice, which makes no sense. It's also unclear why you'd pass f to json.dump. Please fix your question so that people can reproduce your issue.

Indeed, sharing a word file on stack overflow is harder than I thought. It should be working now. Regarding your other comments: Your two last comments are related, the second time I "define" elements I have casted every element in the list to a dictionary to be able to save the output. I also renamed f, as this variable is used twice to f_json the second time.

I didn't find a way using the partition_docx option. But using the ingest library from unstructured it did work. The key is this argument: "extract_image_block_types": ["Image"]. So for all other folks out there struggling with this, give this a try:
import os
import json

# Set environment variables
os.environ['UNSTRUCTURED_API_KEY'] = "your api key"
os.environ['UNSTRUCTURED_API_URL'] = "https://api.unstructuredapp.io/general/v0/general"

from unstructured_ingest.v2.pipeline.pipeline import Pipeline
from unstructured_ingest.v2.interfaces import ProcessorConfig
from unstructured_ingest.v2.processes.connectors.local import (
    LocalIndexerConfig,
    LocalDownloaderConfig,
    LocalConnectionConfig,
    LocalUploaderConfig
)
from unstructured_ingest.v2.processes.partitioner import PartitionerConfig


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Pipeline.from_configs(
        context=ProcessorConfig(),
        indexer_config=LocalIndexerConfig(input_path="input"),
        downloader_config=LocalDownloaderConfig(),
        source_connection_config=LocalConnectionConfig(),
        partitioner_config=PartitionerConfig(
            partition_by_api=True,
            api_key=os.getenv("UNSTRUCTURED_API_KEY"),
            partition_endpoint=os.getenv("UNSTRUCTURED_API_URL"),
            strategy="hi_res",
            additional_partition_args={
                "split_pdf_page": True,
                "split_pdf_allow_failed": True,
                "split_pdf_concurrency_level": 15,
                "extract_image_block_types": ["Image"]
            }
        ),
        uploader_config=LocalUploaderConfig(output_dir="output")
    ).run()

EDIT: I can't get reliable results. I'm resorting to converting to PDF first and then let unstructured analyze the PDF.
